# How to show a widget on top of other widgets in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 app I create a virtual keyboard and I want to show this keyboard on top of other widgets in window whenever I click on show button. I used a Qframe for keyboard and my widgets are in different pages of QStackedWidget. In the code blow the keyboard pushes the other widgets up which is not what I want.

How can I get it to work?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(744, 445)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btnHide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnHide)
        self.btnShow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnShow)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.keyboardFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.keyboardFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 0))
        self.keyboardFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 93, 142);")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.keyboardFrame)
        self.keyboardLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.keyboardFrame)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.keyboardLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.keyboardLayout.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.keyboardLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.keyboardFrame, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.btnHide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.keyboard('hide'))
        self.btnShow.clicked.connect(lambda: self.keyboard('show'))

    def keyboard(self, i):
        height = self.keyboardFrame.height()

        if i == 'show' and height > 0:
            return

        if i == 'hide':
            height = 200
            newHeight = 0
        else:
            height = 0
            newHeight = 200

        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.keyboardFrame, b"maximumHeight")
        self.animation.setDuration(250)
        self.animation.setStartValue(height)
        self.animation.setEndValue(newHeight)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
        self.animation.start()
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnHide.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "hide"))
        self.btnShow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "show"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "KeyBoard"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: But if widgets are not "pushed", the keyboard can potentially hide widgets in which you should type and that should be kept visible.

Comment: @musicamante I have considered this problem, but there are many widgets in my window, and due to this behavior, the keyboard is not fully displayed.

Comment: The problem still remains, especially if there are many widgets: if the keyboard covers them, users won't know on which field they're actually "typing". I understand your main problem, but there's no simple solution; with your current code it's almost impossible to provide you a proper answer (and it also shows that you're still not experienced enough to do what you want to). The basic concept would be to create the keyboard with the main window as parent and *outside* the central widget's layout (which is *not* possible from Designer, you have to do it by code).

Comment: But then you'll have other problems: you need to identify the widget that would be used for the virtual keyboard, get their geometry and eventually scroll the central widget's contents accordingly to ensure that that widget is visible, and then restore the scroll position when the keyboard is hidden. That's *doable*, but not easy, and your question shows that you still lack important knowledge that is mandatory for what you want to do. For instance, why are you editing a pyuic generated file, while ignoring the warning about ***not*** doing it unless you *really* know what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are other more robust solutions, but a simple one with minor changes could be to make self.verticalLayout a QtWidgets.QGridLayout, instead of QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout. This way we can take advantage of the possibility to force the row and column in the layout (see the docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1) and overlap both widgets.

So, on line 7,

```
self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
```

and on line, 31,

```
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.keyboardFrame, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would be grateful if you provide a more robust answer. With these changes the keyboard is displayed in the middle of screen which does not seem very interesting.